# How to extend ansible playbooks to achieve complex conditions?

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts, ansible-template

I understand that ansible is limited to being a configuration tool i.e., we create configurations in yaml files and python scripts does execution by looking at the configuration.

There are howevever a useful attribute `when` that will help in deciding which configuration to be done based on the condition mentioned in `when` and the order of the configurations is also done based on the order of the tasks,

variables and facts are available in achieving dynamic configurations.

However, my requirement involves complex loops and conditions and recursive processing which is either entirely not achievable in playbooks or multiple tasks need to be created with the conditions.

Few issues I find in using ansible playbooks are:

- No if else structures
- loops has very limited functionality
- variable scopes does not work like in scripting languages

And the issue with recursive tasks is like for example:

- `start_installation.yml` does installation of packages defined in a variable
- The package has dependencies and the dependencies has dependencies i.e., recursive dependencies and installation should be done on the dependencies first recursively by calling `start_installation.yml`. However, this is creating problems with the variable scoping i.e., if a package_to_install is 'A' at the time of starting `start_installation.yml` for A, and if A has dependency 'B', then package_to_install will be set to 'B', at the time of starting `start_installation.yml` for B. Now, once installation of B is done, it can't do installation of A, as the variable scope is not local to the called function.

My question is mainly if it is a correct approach to use Ansible in doing these tasks or do I need to use a scripting language to do the required checks?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question:

> " ... it is a correct approach to use Ansible in doing these tasks or do I need to use a scripting language to do the required checks?

Correct approach is to use [package – Generic OS package manager](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/package_module.html). If this does not work [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Thanks for the links..I can't use OS package manager in this case, as my installation  is from source code. However, I will go though the documentation again. It seems I am so used to scripting and it's being little difficult to adjust to ansible way :)

Comment: "installation from source code" does not scale. It's about time to move on :)